# gcc without optimization gives error (but I have to omit -o to enable gdb functions)

Tags: c, gdb

I want to compile my c code without -o optimization (like $ gcc -g test test.c),I don't think the code is causing the problem because I tested simple code like the following and it won't work either:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

and I got a whole bunch of errs like:

```
test: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first d   efined here
test:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
test: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
test:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
test: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

I googled and found that is because I didn't put -o there. But I have to, otherwise commands like "print var" wouldn't work on gdb. Is there anyway I can get around with this?

Thank you!

Comment: `-o` doesn't control optimizations; it specifies that the next command-line argument is the output file name!

Comment: Oh.. so could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing some actual code that causes this problem.  If you are doing `gcc -g -o test test.c`, then can you edit your question to show the context of `test.c`?

Comment: I just did, but I don't think it's the code...

Comment: That should compile just fine with `gcc -g -o test test.c`.

Comment: I know, but I need to omit -o in order to make gdb work.

Comment: If you omit `-o`, your application will be called `a.out` (the default) rather than `test`.  I don't see why this has anything to do with GDB.  To run it in GDB, after compiling, just type `gdb test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is the following:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

Which creates an executable test (`-o` means the output goes to the argument, in this case `test`). For optimisations you use `-O` (a uppercase O).

Now you do:

```
gcc -g test test.c
```

Which tells `gcc` to compile using the `-g` switch (enable debug symbols) and to use the files `test` and `test.c` for compilation. So your error messages arise by gcc trying to compile the executable file `test`, which obviously is no C source file. You would get a similar result just by typing:

```
gcc test
```

Instead run

```
gcc -g -o test test.c
```

as already suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of the -O flags, (capital letter "O"), which control optimization. The -o flag just gives your executable a name. If you don't specify that flag, your executable automatically gets named a.out

I am thinking you might have accidentally typed something like

```
gcc -g test.c test.c
```

which would cause duplicate symbol errors like the ones you showed above. The correct gcc invocation would be:

```
gcc -g -o test test.c
```

If you are looking to get maximum debugging information try `-ggdb3` instead of `-g`

Answer (score 0):

the default optimization level is -O1 if you want to disable optimizations entirely,
you must also pass -O0 to gcc, that is the letter capital O and the number zero.